# How to run .sh file by double clicking in XFCE?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, executable, xfce

I am trying to make a script file. Everything works fine, but it only starts from the terminal.

I already made it executable using `chmod +x filename.sh`, but it won't run.

I saw a solution:

```sh
xfconf-query --channel thunar --property /misc-exec-shell-scripts-by-default \ 
             --create --type bool --set true '
```

But even this doesn't work.

Comment: double clicking where in xfce, in thunar ?

Comment: Yes, for example in Documents, Pictures, and so on.

Comment: You must tell more. What do you want to do ? What is you script ? [ask]

Comment: Nothing big, just a file that executes "sudo service network-manager restart" (I have #!/bin/bash at the top) . The computer has a wireless adapter problem (randomly disconnecting from Wi-Fi and it works again only by restarting the network-manager), and the user isn't familiar with command prompt usage, so I decided to make this script. Every time it disconnects, the user will double click it to resolve the problem.

Comment: There is nothing to do with thunar. Try to add it in the application menu.

Comment: A simple script with `#!/bin/bash notify-send foo` works for me (Thunar 1.8.6). And yes, `misc-exec-shell-scripts-by-default` is enabled here. Try to run thunar from terminal (first finish the daemon with `thunar -q`) and watch for error messages.

Comment: Thanks, everything mentioned helped!

Answer (score 10):

Ran into the same problem tonight, took a lot of digging but I got it! (on mobile so formatting might be wack)

1. make sure you have the proper `#!/bin/bash/` shebang
2. right click file-> permissions-> check "allow to run as program"
3. in terminal run: `xfconf-query --channel thunar --property /misc-exec-shell-scripts-by-default --create --type bool --set true`

this last step is what makes the difference in xfce. Thunar (The xfce file manager) doesn't by default have this setting so you need to add it yourself.

**If you are more comfortable in a gui:**
do steps 1-2 above, then:

1)get into xfce4-settings-editor (You can find it by searching with alt+F2)

2)click thunar on the menu in the right

3)hit "new", set the type to boolean set to true and the property to `/misc-exec-shell-scripts-by-default`

**either way make sure you don't have a file manager/thunar window open**

If you want to read more about these "Hidden settings" in thunar, check out the docs!
https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/hidden-settings

**EDIT**:
Someone asked about how to make the command open a new terminal window, thought I'd throw that down here.
My method for doing this is to "wrap" your command like this:

```
xfce4-terminal --command "your_command_here"
```

This could be placed inside your executable, or you could make a file specifically for running your executable, like runner.sh or something

Comment: I did this and now I have an "Execute" item in the right click menu. However, I was expecting that a terminal window would open upon clicking on that menu item or upon double clicking, like shell scripts do on Windows. I require that because the script is interactive. How can I the terminal to open?

Comment: Hey just got to this and updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

Resolved problem by right-click on executable file, then "open with" -> "open with other application", in "Use a custom command" wrote "/bin/sh" and check "Use as default..."

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a shebang to your script. The first line should be something line this

```sh
#!/bin/bash
```

That is all I needed to do to make a script work with double click from Thunar like you mentioned.

Comment: Does not work for me. Shebang, +x , open with "Xfce Terminal". Still no luck.